i cant pass the automated test
def topN_pos(csv_file_path, N):
    """
    Example:
    >>> topN_pos('train.csv', 3)
    output would look like [(noun1, 22), (noun2, 10), ...]
    """
    # Load the CSV file
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_file_path)

    # Use 'qtext' column for text
    text_data = df['qtext'].tolist()

    # Tokenize sentences and words, and apply POS tagging
    all_words = []
    for sentence in text_data:
        words = word_tokenize(sentence)
        pos_tags = nltk.pos_tag(words, tagset="universal")
        # Filter for nouns only
        nouns = [word for word, pos in pos_tags if pos == 'NOUN']
        all_words.extend(nouns)

    # Count frequency of each noun
    word_counter = collections.Counter(all_words)

    # Get the top N most common nouns
    most_common_nouns = word_counter.most_common(N)

    return most_common_nouns 
this is my code i have a data set and an automated test to solve but im not gettint the right frequencies 

this is my code and im not getting the desired output with my wordcounter there is this automated test that im trying to pass but i keep getting the same error msg
[('cancer', 731), ('symptoms', 521), ('help', 400)] this is what u got
[('cancer', 157), ('symptoms', 116), ('help', 87)]) this is what i was expecting 

please if anyone could help me fix it

What's the error message?

There is no error it just doesn’t match the expected outputs
